# ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag in class XY

Tags: java

I have a piece of code in which I try to load a class during runtime. The code is not all selfwritten so I have some problems understanding the error which always appers after compiling.

Here the code:

```
private Class findClass(String s)
        throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        URL url = getResource("AP.class");
        if(url == null)
        {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(s);
        }
        inputstream = null;
        Class classToRead;
        try
        {
            inputstream = url.openStream();
            byte abyte0[] = readClass(inputstream);
            classToRead= defineClass(s, abyte0, 0, abyte0.length);
        }
        catch(IOException ioexception)
        {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(s);
        }
        if(inputstream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                inputstream.close();
            }
            catch(Exception exception1) { }
        }
        return classToRead;
    }
```

The error appears at the defineClass method.

Error stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 63 in class file AP
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at c.findClass(c.java:100)
    at c.loadClass(c.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at c.a(c.java:20)
    at mainOpenClass.main(lol.java:13)
```

My questions now are:
Is maybe anything wrong with the code?
Is it possible that the AP.class is damaged?
What does the error really mean?

I hope anybody can help me with my problem because searching the internet didn't really help in that case.

Comment: how is it that you are throwing `ClassNotFoundException` when an `IOException` is caught?

Comment: I think the error is not an IOException so it is caught later.

Answer (score 10):

The code you've written yourself is fine. The problem is that `AP.class` is a damaged class file -- hence the `ClassFormatError`.

The error itself means that it failed to correctly decode the *constant pool*, a section of the class file structure that is much like a symbol table. See [§4.4 of the Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4):

> Java virtual machine instructions do not rely on the runtime layout of classes, interfaces, class instances, or arrays. Instead, instructions refer to symbolic information in the `constant_pool` table.
>
> All `constant_pool` table entries have the following general format:
>
> ```
> cp_info {
>     u1 tag;
>     u1 info[];
> }
> ```
>
> Each item in the `constant_pool` table must begin with a 1-byte tag indicating the kind of `cp_info` entry. The contents of the info array vary with the value of tag. The valid tags and their values are listed in [Table 4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4-140). Each tag byte must be followed by two or more bytes giving information about the specific constant. The format of the additional information varies with the tag value.

So, the error itself is telling you that the class has a constant pool table entry with an invalid tag, namely `63`. Verifying with Table 4.3 mentioned above, indeed, **this does not correspond to any documented kind of `cp_info` entry**.

Try to re-download `AP.class`. Given the obscure names (`AP`, as well as `c` from the stack trace), I'm going to assume you're trying to use some obfuscated code. Verify not only that the code you're trying to deal with is not further protected by some sort of encryption, but also that any preprocessing you do (e.g. deobfuscation) does not corrupt the data.

Comment: I assume with "the code you're trying to deal with" you mean the code in AP.class. With that assumption I am not sure how to check for any encryption. Is there an easy way to check that? PS: thanks for that great answer!

Comment: Find the code that normally uses `AP.class` and see if it does any preprocessing before defining the class. It might be encrypting it.

Comment: Thats the problem, I don't have such a code. That is the first time in the code that the class appears. Some background information so that my question does not sound ultimatively stupid. The code is part of a challenge where you get a java program, must decompile it and find a password. My assumption is that the password is in this class which I am not able to read. Could you imagine any way how to read the class with only that knowledge?

Comment: if you can tell me how I should send you the zip ^^

Comment: @Mister004 something like dropbox or puush is hassle-free.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/103884087/client.rar ... but be warned it is extremly and unnessecarily complicated. The main method is in the commons-codec-1.3.jar in the Client class and the others are in the client.jar

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions:

1. No
2. Yes
3. [From Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassFormatError.html) Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine attempts to
   read a class file and determines that the file is malformed or
   otherwise cannot be interpreted as a class file.

Comment: Ok thanks. That means without having the source code of AP.class but only the file itself it is not possible for me to read the class? Or is there any way to "recover" the class?

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunatelly there is also an error if I decompile it directly.

Comment: it happens because class file is damaged